# Best way to delete a file asynchronously in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

There are posts from several (4) years ago showing how to use Threads to delete a file asynchronously.

Things have moved on though, what with aiofiles etc. Its all a bit of a maze, so am I missing a current, elegant method to achieve this without Threading ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to work with file I/O asynchronously without threads [due to operation systems limits](https://github.com/python/asyncio/wiki/ThirdParty#filesystem). It's not related to Python or asyncio at all.

The best way to work with file I/O asynchronously now - is [aiofiles](https://github.com/Tinche/aiofiles) library usage.